# map does not take background color parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I map over an Array, and when I get the Array from "axios", I also add a new parameter "color".
In real life I should have `colors = []` and the map each color for each card, but let's keep it simple:

```
const colors = "#248531";
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
const fetch = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
      },
    });
    setCards(response?.data.results);
    cards.map((el) => (el.color = colors));
  } catch (err) {
  }
```

This is the log:

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'name', categories: Array(10), color: '#248531'}
```

But when I map over the "cards" I don't get the actual color:

```
{cards
        .map((el, index) => (
          <CustomCard
            key={index}
            text={el.name}
            backgroundColor={el.color}></CustomCard>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use `setState` to update the `state`, you shouldn't update it directly like `cards.map((el) => (el.color = colors));`

Second, you `map` method should return the mapped object but in your case it always returns `true` which is the result of assigning operation `(el) => (el.color = colors)`

So, you can `map` over the `response?.data.results` before setting it to the `cards`.

```
const colors = "#248531";
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
const fetch = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
      },
    });
    const result = response?.data.results;
    if (result) {
      setCards(result.map((el) => ({
        ...el,
        color: colors
      })));
    }
  } catch (err) {
  }
```